# Create a half circle instead pyramid in scatterplot

Tags: r, plot, geometry

I would like to have a half circle instead a pyramid pattern in a R scatterplot. This is my current code to produce a pyramid:

```
startx <- 101
endx <- 200

x = seq(from=startx, to=endx, by=1)

inx = length(x)
y1 <- seq(from=1, to=inx, by=2)
y2 <- sort(y1, decreasing = TRUE)
y = c(y1, y2)

plot(x,y)
```

[image]
Some idea to change the dots distribution to represent a half circle instead?

Comment: You should try to contribute your own thoughts on what you would need to change to reach your goals. Then it's easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going!

```
startx <- -50
endx <- 50

x = seq(from=startx, to=endx, by=0.1)

y <- sqrt(50^2-x^2)

y <- y * 2

x <- x + 150

plot(x,y)
```

[image]